# Fixed effects in a cross-sectional data set

Tags: multivariate-analysis, least-squares, stata, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I am conducting a research with a cross sectional data set (1 year, multiple countries). Now i am researching the likelihood of supportive leadership and firmsize. Now firm size is a catogorical variable (1-4), my teacher has advised me to create binary variables 0 or 1 for each category, excluding one (adding firm fixed effects), however i don't understand how to do this?
Should i add i.firmsize? Or is there a better way to this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is giving you a correct suggestion.

For categorical predictors, one usually defines a *dummy variable* which encodes the fact that one observation belongs to one category or another.
This is a general approach, so I'll show you a simple one fixed-effect model.
Let's say that we have one categorical predictor $X$ that may assume 3 values $X \in \{X_1,X_2,X_3\}, \, i=1\ldots,N$. We want to fit a linear model between and a continuous random variable $Y$. Let's say that we have $N$ observations.
Then a linear model would be represented by the equation

$$
Y=X\beta+\epsilon
$$

or

$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon, \quad i=1,\ldots,N
$$

Now, since we have three possible categories for $X$, using the three possible categories doesn't make sense, because $X_1, X_2, X_3$ can be numbers or other categories and we don't know how to multiply categories by slope coefficients.
Instead, since we are interested in modelling the *difference* in average of $Y$ between the different categories, we can use a mathematical trick introducing the *dummy variables*.

In our case, since we have 3 possible categories, we set one as reference (this will be modelled as the intercept of the model) and the other two as variables shifted by **one unit**:

$$
X_{dummy} = \pmatrix {0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}
$$

where the first column is always equal to 0, the second column is equal to 1 for the samples (rows) $x_i=X2$ and the third column is equal to 1 for the samples $x_i=X3$.
With this encoding the model becomes this:

$$
y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 * x^{(dummy)}_{i,1} + \beta_2 * x^{(dummy)}_{i,2} + \beta_3 * x^{(dummy)}_{i,3} + \epsilon
$$

which means that if $x_i=X1$, then $x^{(dummy)}_{i,1}=0, x^{(dummy)}_{i,2}=0, x^{(dummy)}_{i,3}=0$, giving the equation:

$$
y_i^{(X1)}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 * 0 + \beta_2 * 0 + \beta_3 * 0 + \epsilon = \beta_0 + \epsilon
$$

if $x_i=X2$, then $x^{(dummy)}_{i,1}=0, x^{(dummy)}_{i,2}=1, x^{(dummy)}_{i,3}=0$, giving the equation:

$$
y_i^{(X2)}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 * 0 + \beta_2 * 1 + \beta_3 * 0 + \epsilon = \beta_0 + \beta_2 + \epsilon
$$

and if $x_i=X3$, then $x^{(dummy)}_{i,1}=0, x^{(dummy)}_{i,2}=0, x^{(dummy)}_{i,3}=1$, giving the equation:

$$
y_i^{(X3)}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 * 0 + \beta_2 * 0 + \beta_3 * 1 + \epsilon = \beta_0 + \beta_3 + \epsilon
$$

We can simplify by dropping $\beta_1$ (and renaming $\beta_2=\beta_1$, and $\beta_3=\beta_2$) because it's always equal to 0, getting a linear model

$$
y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_2 * x^{(dummy)}_{i,2} + \beta_3 * x^{(dummy)}_{i,3} + \epsilon
$$

After seeing how the model encodes the 3 categories, it becomes easy to see how the parameters can be interpreted:

$$
y_i^{(X1)} = \beta_0 + \epsilon
$$

the intercept $\beta_0$ represents the average $Y$ for the samples belonging to category $X_1$.

$$
y_i^{(X2)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + \epsilon
$$

the first coefficient $\beta_1$ represents the **average difference** between the $Y$ of category $X_2$ and $X_1$ samples.
And finally,

$$
y_i^{(X3)} = \beta_0 + \beta_2 + \epsilon
$$

the first coefficient $\beta_2$ represents the **average difference** between the $Y$ of category $X_3$ and $X_1$ samples.

*Important*: is this the only way to encode the categories into a linear model? No. There are other ways, each of them requiring an opportune change in the interpretation of the model parameters.

*Practical aspects*:

if you use R, this is automatically done by setting the categorical variable as a *factor*.

```
X <- sample(c("c1", "c2", "c3"), 20, replace=TRUE)
Y <- rnorm(20)

X <- factor(X)

model.matrix(Y~X, data.frame(X, Y))
```

gives you:

```
   (Intercept) Xc2 Xc3
1            1   1   0
2            1   0   0
3            1   0   1
4            1   0   0
5            1   0   0
6            1   0   0
7            1   1   0
8            1   0   0
9            1   0   0
10           1   1   0
11           1   0   1
12           1   1   0
13           1   0   1
14           1   0   1
15           1   1   0
16           1   0   1
17           1   1   0
18           1   0   1
19           1   1   0
20           1   0   0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$X
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

with the intercept all equal to 1 for the formulation $Y=X\beta$, with $\beta=(\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate explanation, it is much more clear now! I am using stata, do you know which commands are best to use?

Comment: You are welcome! No sorry, I’m not expert of stata. I usually use R.

Comment: @Sabine iis id, to declare id, or whatever you call the variable that links the rows into a group. Then, xtreg y x,fe where y is your dependent and x the list of independent variables. This is "de-meaning" y and x, which is equivalent, but more efficient to fitting a dummy variable per id.

Comment: In Stata you can just go "i.firmsize" as you suggest in the OP to generate the dummy variables. Note that if you do that it will treat the biggest category as the reference category. If you want to force a specific category to be the reference you can type (for example) "ib1.firmsize" to make "1" the reference ("base") category.